# Alternating least square formula

Tags: machine-learning, matrix, recommender-system, linear-algebra

So I was reading about the alternating least square algorithm used for movie recommendations.

Let's say that:

X - user ratings

Y - movie ratings

The result is computed by this formula:

[image]

In the book I am reading about this it is mentioned that at each step we compute:

[image]

Why do we use this formula and not $X_i = A_i(Y^T)^{-1}$ where $(Y^T)^{-1}$ is the inverse of $Y$ transposed?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confusing the rating matrix with the loss function. The goal is to achieve $X_i$ and $Y_i$ such that they minimize this loss function*:

$$ \underset{X,Y}{\operatorname{Argmin}} \big \|R- X Y^T \big \|_F^2\tag{$1$}$$

One of the typical ways to optimize a loss function, is by taking its derivative and setting it to $0$ and solving for the variable you are trying to minimize or maximize.

Taking the derivative of $(1)$ in terms of $X$ (holding $Y$ constant) yields:
$$X = RY(Y^T Y)^{-1}\tag{$2$}$$

Taking the derivative of $(1)$ in terms of $Y$ (holding $X$ constant) yields:
$$Y = RX(X^T X)^{-1}\tag{$3$}$$

I wish I could show you the math behind this derivation but it can get pretty hairy and is a question in of itself. However, it would be a good exercise to really convince yourself rather than believing it at face value.

Now, alternating least squares works by first assigning random values to matrix $Y$ and solving for $X$ $(2)$. Then fixing $X$ constant, you solve for $Y$ $(3)$. The algorithm iterates through these steps until $X$ and $Y$ converge to a local optimum.

***Note**, that I left out the regularization terms accompanied by $\lambda$ for brevity. These terms are almost always part of this formula $(1)$ to combat overfitting.

Comment: how do i find the derivative ? can you show the full step

Comment: @kong I can't quite remember how the derivatives of transpose matrices are done and since the question was never accepted, I never looked into it further.

Answer (score 2):

just addition to guy answer and Kong question
so after derivation of formula with respect to X and equating to 0 you get:
$$
2(R-XY^T)(-Y^T) = 0
$$
so
$$
R Y^T = X Y^T Y^T
$$
and reminding that inverse matrix exists for square matrix you need to do following steps:

1. both sides multiply by Y
   $$
   R(Y^TY) = XY^T(Y^TY)
   $$
2. $Y^TY$ is square so if not singular then inverse matrix exists so we can multiply both sides with $(Y^TY)^{-1}$ getting unit matrix
   $$
   R = XY^T
   $$
3. repeat step 1
   $$
   RY = X(Y^TY)
   $$
4. repeat set 2
   $$
   RY(Y^TY)^{-1} = X
   $$
   for derivation wrt Y
   $$
   2(R-XY^T)(-X^T)=0
   $$
   because $d(A^T)=(dA)^T$ so $d(XY^T)=X^T$
   and rest computation is similar